# Checkboxes values not saving with has_many through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes, has-many-through, strong-parameters

For my Room edit form, I'm trying to associate 2 has_many through relationships with the same models (Color and Room)

where is my join model migration :

#### color_preferences

```
class CreateColorPreferences < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :color_preferences do |t|
      t.references :color
      t.references :room
      t.string :value

      t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

end

The column "value" can have these values:

- Love
- Hate

I have the following models with the current relationships :

#### room.rb

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :color_preferences
   has_many :colors, through: :color_preferences
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :color_preferences
end
```

#### color.rb

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :color_preferences
  has_many :rooms, through: :color_preferences
end
```

and my join model :

#### color_preference.rb

```
class ColorPreference < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :color
  belongs_to :room

end
```

my controller :

#### rooms_controller.rb :

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_room, only: :edit

  def edit
    @love_colors = if @room.color_preferences.where(value: "love").present?
      @room.color_preferences.where(value: "love")
    else
      @room.color_preferences.build
    end
    @hate_colors = if @room.color_preferences.where(value: "hate").present?
      @room.color_preferences.where(value: "hate")
    else
      @room.color_preferences.build
    end
  end

  private

  def set_room
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  end

  def room_params
    params.require(:room).permit(color_preferences_attributes: [:id, :value, color_id: []])
  end
end
```

and my view :

#### room/edit.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for @room do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :color_preferences, @love_colors do |cp|
    = cp.association :color, as: :check_boxes
    = cp.hidden_field :value, value: "love"
  = f.simple_fields_for :color_preferences, @hate_colors do |cp|
    = cp.association :color, as: :check_boxes
    = cp.hidden_field :value, value: "hate"
```

If I look at the parameters I have the following :

```
"room"=>{"color_preferences_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"color_id"=>["11", "12", "13", ""], "value"=>"love"}, "1"=>{"color_id"=>["1", "2", "3", ""], "value"=>"hate"}}
```

But colors aren't save in the ColorPreferences Table :

```
[#<ColorPreference id: 1, color_id: nil, room_id: 1, value: "love", created_at: "2016-05-08 12:55:29", updated_at: "2016-05-08 12:55:29">...]
```

My two questions are :

- What's wrong with my setup not saving color_id values ?
- Did I set my edit method correctly in order to retrieve color values in my form? In fact If I set a color id for a specific entry I didn't get the value selected.
  Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

In your attributes, you need to send `color_ids` instead of `color_id` in your params.

In fact, your form code could be made a lot simpler if you reference the `colors` association directly from `@room`:

```
= simple_form_for @room do |f|
  = f.input :color_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: @love_colors, value_method: :id, label_method: :value
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your answer. However, I can't use direct association as you suggested because I need to store the extra params "value" (hate or love) in my join table. So I decided to use a nested form (color_preferences) for this purpose. but in that case i can't use color_ids as the model doesn't know the relation.